# How can I do a SELECT with IF clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I do a select that IF San_Cliente.NomeCompleto IS NOT NULL THEN San_Cliente.Excluido = 0  ?

Nowaday this is my SELECT

```
SELECT  Key.Key_Id, 
        Key.User_Id, 
        Key.From, 
        su.CompleteName, 
        Key.Company_Id, 
        Key.User_Id_Responsible, 
        Key.DateTime, 
        Key.Transaction, 
        Key.Client_Id, 
        Key.DateTimeGet, 
        Key.DateTimeDelivered, 
        Key.Hours, 
        Key.ResponsibleName, 
        Key.PersonalId,
        User.CompleteName AS NomeUsuarioVenda, 
        Client.CompleteName 
FROM    San_Chave 
JOIN    User 
    ON  Key.User_Id_Responsible = User.User_Id 
JOIN    User su 
    ON  Key.User_Id = su.User_Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Client
    ON  Key.Client_Id = Client.Client_Id 
WHERE   (Key.Delivered = 0 OR Key.Delivered is NULL) 
    and Key.From = 14
    AND User.Deleted = 0
```

In my WHERE clause, I need put AND Client.Deleted = 0, but just if Client.CompleteName is not null.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Your table and field names are written in strange words I can't begin to understand.

Comment: Let me translate, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very end, add this condition

```
AND (San_Cliente.NomeCliente is null OR San_Cliente.Excluido = 0)
```

So if `San_Cliente.NomeCliente` IS null, the record passes the WHERE clause.
When it `IS NOT NULL`, then it checks the additional filter.

To summarize,

- IF San_Cliente.NomeCompleto IS NOT NULL THEN this condition is added to the WHERE clause: `AND San_Cliente.Excluido = 0`
- IF San_Cliente.NomeCompleto IS NULL THEN the condition is NOT added

Comment: But I need to put the San_Cliente.Excluido = 0, JUST IF San_Cliente.NomeCompleto is null.

Comment: Which is it? Your question states `but just if Client.CompleteName is `**not**` null`

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry. JUST IF Client.CompleteName is not null. If Client.CompleteName is not null, I have to put the Client.Deleted = 0

Comment: Then the answer is given above. Give it a test

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
(San_Chave.NomeCompleto IS NULL or (San_Cliente.NomeCompleto IS NOT NULL AND San_Cliente.Excluido = 0))
```

There might be a more concise way to represent this logical situation, but I think this will, regardless, be the clearest.

Comment: Make sure you know exactly what question you're asking: Make a truth table with NomeCompleto is/is not null on one axis and Excluido is/is not 0 on the other, and figure out whether you want to include or exclude the row based on that.  If the answer isn't apparent, tell me your truth table and I'll try to suggest the WHERE conditions that make it work.

Comment: JUST IF Client.CompleteName is not null. If Client.CompleteName is not null, I have to put the Client.Deleted = 0

Comment: You're wording this like it's a function in a programming language, not a SQL query.  Making a truth table will help you form your question into a SQL query.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Comment: Instead of thinking "if x, put in this condition" think of it as "if x and y, return true".

Answer (score 1):

Use coalesce

```
coalesce(San_Cliente,0) = 0
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

```
SELECT San_Chave.Chave_Id, San_Chave.Usuario_Id, San_Chave.De, su.NomeCompleto, 
San_Chave.Credenciada_Id, San_Chave.Usuario_Id_Responsavel, San_Chave.DataHora, 
San_Chave.Transacao, San_Chave.Cliente_Id, San_Chave.DataHoraPegou, 
San_Chave.DataHoraDevolverPrevisao, San_Chave.DataHoraEntregou, 
San_Chave.HorasDevolucao, San_Chave.NomeResponsavel, San_Chave.CpfResponsavel, 
San_Chave.RgResponsavel, San_Chave.TelResponsavel, San_Chave.Tel2Responsavel, 
San_Chave.Endereco, San_Chave.Devolvido, San_Chave.TextoDevolucao, 
San_Usuario.NomeCompleto AS NomeUsuarioVenda, San_Cliente.NomeCompleto 
FROM San_Chave JOIN San_Usuario 
ON San_Chave.Usuario_Id_Responsavel = San_Usuario.Usuario_Id 
JOIN San_Usuario su 
ON San_Chave.Usuario_Id = su.Usuario_Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN San_Cliente 
ON San_Chave.Cliente_Id = San_Cliente.Cliente_Id 
WHERE (San_Chave.Devolvido = 0 OR San_Chave.Devolvido is NULL) 
and San_Chave.De = 14
AND San_Usuario.Excluido = 0 
AND coalesce(San_Cliente,0) = 0
```